# How to get EasyMock.verify() to fail on unexpected calls

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

EasyMock's behavior on unexpected calls is to throw an exception. Ideally, this propagates up to the test method, causing the test to fail. I have some code where the call is wrapped in a try-catch and I can't rely on that exception to cause the test to fail. Instead, I'm using `EasyMock.verify()`, but it passes.

```
Function f = EasyMock.strictMock(Function.class);
EasyMock.replay(f);
try {
    f.apply("");
} catch (Throwable t) {
    // apply() isn't mocked, so an exception is thrown and caught here
    System.out.println(t);
}

// This call passes
EasyMock.verify(f);
```

A partial workaround is to use a `Capture` and check how many times a method's been called, but that only checks on the captured methods, not all methods, and checking all methods can be messy.

Comment: `EasyMock.verify` can only be used to check if methods on mock objects have been called and the `Throwable` is not a mock object. I think I can not answer your question without seeing the code which should be tested.

Comment: The code above is enough. I want to verify that `f.apply()` is never called. Easymock threw the exception so tests fail. My issue is that the code I'm testing catches exceptions, and I want to verify that the mock is never called.